# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm doing it in Java XML Parser, then I got this error when parsing an xml file...

> [Fatal Error] jira.xml:192:64: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
>         at com.icomteq.ReadXMLFile.main(ReadXMLFile.java:20)

Any clue what could be the problem? Thank you.

**Here is the code used** ->
http://s29.postimg.org/tjbzvsn3b/xmlreader.jpg

**Here is my jira.xml** ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DATA_RECORD>
<DESCRIPTION>
&lt;< inside &amp;& the description tag &lt;<
</DESCRIPTION>
</DATA_RECORD>
```

**Temporary solution** ->
I figured out that XML Norms `<` should not be in the xml, so I will use `contents.toString().replaceAll("&lt;<", "&lt;").replaceAll("&amp;&", "&amp;")`

Comment: Post the Original XML which you want to parse.. Not the Edited one

Answer (score 6):

To me it looks like you have an encoding problem with this line.

```
&lt;< inside &amp;& the description tag &lt;<
```

should either be

`&lt;&lt; inside &amp;&amp; the description tag &lt;&lt;`

or it should be

```
&lt; inside &amp; the description tag &lt;
```

Comment: I read somewhere that we can also use CDATA to 'wrap' the special characters in SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
I used XML Comment markup for JS to make it work in XML
<script>
  <!-- 
     
     [Place your Javascript here]
  
  -->
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).